404 Error page is not displaying on subpages
Here is code of 404 page,
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Image from 'next/image';
export default function PageNotFound() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const redirectToHome = () => router.push('/');
  return (
    <section className='bg-home d-flex align-items-center py-5 mt-3'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-md-12 text-center'>
            <a href={undefined} className='btn btn-primary' onClick={redirectToHome}>
              Go To Home
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}


and here is my portfolio subpage component
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import 'swiper/css';
import Hero from '../Hero';
import { projects } from '../../utils/staticData';
import { convertImage, toBase64 } from '../../utils/helper';

export default function ProjectDetails({ id }) {
  const projectDetail = projects?.find((project) => project?.title.replace(/ /g, `_`) === id);
  const viewMoreProjects = projects?.filter((project) => project?.title.replace(/ /g, '_') !== id);

  return (
    <>
      <Hero
        title={projectDetail?.title}
      />
      <section className='details'>
        {projectDetail?.slider.map((item, index) => (
          <section className={`section overflow-hidden ${index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-light' : 'bg-white'}`} id='contact' key={index}>
            <div className='container'>
              <div className={`row  ${index % 2 === 1 ? 'flex-row-reverse' : ''}`}>
                <div className='col-md-7 col-12'>
                  {projectDetail?.headings?.[index] && (
                    <h4 className='section-title mb-4 py-2' data-aos='fade-up' data-aos-duration={1000} data-aos-once='true'>
                      <h4 className='title'>{projectDetail?.headings[index]}</h4>
                    </h4>
                  )}
                  <p className='text-muted para-desc' data-aos='fade-up' data-aos-duration={1000} data-aos-once='true'>
                    <ul className='list-unstyled text-muted'>
                      {projectDetail?.listData[projectDetail?.headings[index]].map((headingsContent, subIndex) => (
                        <li className='mb-0 d-flex mt-2' data-aos='fade-left' data-aos-duration={1400} data-aos-once='true' key={subIndex}>
                          <span className='text-primary h4 ' style={headingsContent.item.length <= 75 ? { lineHeight: '20px' } : {}}>
                            <i className='uil uil-check-circle  align-middle' />
                          </span>
                          <span className='ms-3'>
                            <>
                              {headingsContent?.item}
                              {headingsContent?.link}
                            </>
                          </span>
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className='col-md-5 col-12'>
                  <img
                    src={item}
                    alt={`${projectDetail.title} Image`}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        ))}
      </section>
      {projectDetail?.techStack.length >= 2 && (
        <section className='d-table w-100 py-5' style={{ backgroundColor: '#202942' }}>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center py-4'>
              <h3 className='section-title text-center text-muted '>Technologies</h3>
            </div>
            <div className='row justify-content-center py-4'>
              {projectDetail?.techStack?.map(({ src, alt }, index) => (
                <div className='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-6 text-center py-4' key={index}>
                  <Image src={src} className='avatar avatar-ex-sm' alt={alt} width={105} height={34} />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      )}
      <section className='section'>
        <div className='container'>
          <Link href='/portfolio' key='view more'>
            <h5 className='section-title text-center mb-5 text-primary' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
              View More
            </h5>
          </Link>
          <div className='row'>
            {viewMoreProjects?.slice(0, 3).map((project, i) => (
              <Link key={i} href={`/portfolio/${project?.title.replace(/ /g, '_')}`}>
                <div className='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 pb-2' key={i} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                  <div className='card border-1  position-relative d-block overflow-hidden rounded'>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

I want to add functionality for a 404 Error page. Currently, the 404 Error page is functioning correctly for the Home page, Partner page, and Portfolio page. However, there seems to be an issue specifically with the portfolio subpages. Despite my efforts, the 404 Error page fails to display when navigating to these subpages within the portfolio section. I've thoroughly examined the code and configuration to identify the root cause of this issue, but unfortunately, I haven't been successful in resolving it yet.
